# Restore Full/Differential backup to a new web application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I was creating a Full and differential backup of a web application with Backup-SPFarm command. Backup thing is working fine for me.

Can anyone have idea how to restore this full backup to a new web application with Restore-SPFarm command ?

I have tried with powershell and SharePoint central administration, but no success and it is not giving any error as well it saying it is successfully completed.

Using these commands for backup and restore

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory 'c:\bkp' -BackupMethod full -Item 'SharePoint - 80' -Verbose

Restore-SPFarm -Directory C:\bkp -RestoreMethod Overwrite -Item "SharePoint - 41434" -BackupId e7e7b9a5-355e-4f6c-b340-c453274b129a -Verbose
```

Anyone have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the restore-log? Are you restoring it to the same server/environment? I'm not sure you can restore it to the same servers since the content-database will be the same. Have you tried to restore it to a dev-environment?